Prevent having to pass in headers for each use in custom axios instance to fix ts error after bump to 1.7.7
I recently bumped my axios from 0.28.0 to 1.7.7 and now I am starting to get ts errors.
Here is my current code:
import axios, {
  AxiosInstance,
  AxiosInterceptorManager,
  AxiosPromise,
  InternalAxiosRequestConfig,
  AxiosResponse,
} from 'axios';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import { appConfig } from '../config/env';

interface RequestConfig extends InternalAxiosRequestConfig {}

interface CustomHttpInstance extends AxiosInstance {
  (config: RequestConfig): AxiosPromise;
  (url: string, config?: RequestConfig): AxiosPromise;
  interceptors: {
    request: AxiosInterceptorManager<RequestConfig>;
    response: AxiosInterceptorManager<AxiosResponse>;
  };
  getUri(config?: RequestConfig): string;
  request<T = any, R = T>(config: RequestConfig): Promise<R>;
  get<T = any, R = T>(url: string, config?: RequestConfig): Promise<R>;
  delete<T = any, R = T>(url: string, config?: RequestConfig): Promise<R>;
  head<T = any, R = T>(url: string, config?: RequestConfig): Promise<R>;
  options<T = any, R = T>(url: string, config?: RequestConfig): Promise<R>;
  post<T = any, R = T>(
    url: string,
    data?: any,
    config?: RequestConfig,
  ): Promise<R>;
  put<T = any, R = T>(
    url: string,
    data?: any,
    config?: RequestConfig,
  ): Promise<R>;
  patch<T = any, R = T>(
    url: string,
    data?: any,
    config?: RequestConfig,
  ): Promise<R>;
}

const customHttpProvider: CustomHttpInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: appConfig.api.baseUrl,
  headers: {
    'X-SIGN-TYPE': 2,
    'X-API-KEY': appConfig.api.apiKey,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

customHttpProvider.interceptors.request.use(async (config: RequestConfig) => {
  const timestamp = Date.now().toString();
  const apiKey = appConfig.api.apiKey;
  const secretKey = appConfig.api.apiSecret;
  const recvWindow = 5000; // in milliseconds
  let payload = '';
  if (config.params && Object.keys(config.params).length) {
    const params = config.params;
    payload = Object.keys(params)
      .map((key) => {
        return `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`;
      })
      .join('&');
  }

  if (config.data) {
    payload = JSON.stringify(config.data);
  }

  const body = timestamp + apiKey + recvWindow + payload;
  const apiSignature = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(
    CryptoJS.algo.SHA256,
    secretKey,
  )
    .update(body)
    .finalize()
    .toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

  config.headers['X-SIGN'] = apiSignature;
  config.headers['X-TIMESTAMP'] = timestamp;
  config.headers['X-RECV-WINDOW'] = recvWindow;

  return config;
});

customHttpProvider.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) =>
    new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(response.data);
    }),

  (error) =>
    new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      reject(error.response?.data ? error.response.data : error);
    }),
);

export default customHttpProvider;

And here is where I use it:
const getBalance = (accountType: string = 'UNIFIED') => {
  return customHttpProvider.get<{
    retCode: number;
    retMsg: string;
    result: {
      memberId: string;
      accountType: string;
      balance: {
        coin: string;
        transferBalance: string;
        walletBalance: string;
        bonus: '';
      }[];
    };
    retExtInfo: Record<string, any>;
    time: number;
  }>('/v5/asset/transfer/query-account-coins-balance', {
    params: {
      accountType,
    },
    // I don't want to pass this header each time to fix ts error
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
};

The issue is that now RequestConfig extends InternalAxiosRequestConfig (instead of earlier AxiosRequestConfig. This means each time I use this customHttpProvider, I am having to pass in the same headers each time. Otherwise I get ts error:
TS2345: Argument of type '{ params: { accountType: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestConfig'.   Property 'headers' is missing in type '{ params: { accountType: string; }; }' but required in type 'InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any>'.

This is really quite tedious and I don't want having to pass in headers each time to fix the ts error. Whats a proper solution to it?

Can you switch from InternalAxiosRequestConfig to just AxiosRequestConfig? I mean, it is the same interface, literally InternalAxiosConfig just makes headers required.
https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/cda671af81ca87a00c6bf5a07bffcb07468756d3/index.d.ts#L316
headers are optional there, while InternalAxiosRequestConfig is perhaps used by Axios itself, that's why they made headers required there
